# Issue with custom right click menu functions

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, right-click

Here's my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Jv9gc/

My problem at the moment is I haven't been able to get my custom right click menu to do anything, not even a simple alertbox. Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please: **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/77L4w/

Hope this will fit the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('#movecam').draggable({
    drag: function() {
        $('#mecam').css('top', $(this).position().top);
        $('#mecam').css('left', $(this).position().left);
    },
    stop: function() {
        $('#mecam').css('top', $(this).position().top);
        $('#mecam').css('left', $(this).position().left);
    }
});

$("#movecam").bind("contextmenu", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
    $("<div class='custom-menu'><input id='propertz' type='button' name='propertz' value='Properties'></div>").appendTo("body").css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });

    init_prperty_click()
}).bind("click", function(event) {
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
});

$('input[name="closeme"]').click(function() {
    $("#movecam").hide();
});

function init_prperty_click() {
    $("input[name=propertz]").on('click', function() {
        alert("haha");
    });
}​
```